# ASP.NET : Load flash movie from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, flash

I have an ASP.NET web page where i need to show a flash movie. the flash movie file name i will get dynamically in my code behind code.Now i want to load this file name to the flash object from code behind. Whats the ways to do this ? Is there any other method i can render a flash movie in a web page other than the OBJECT tag ?

Is there anything to do with a ajax cal here ? any performance improvement we can achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you combine client and server side code on this.  It's not an extremely clean solution; however, it probably will help meet your needs.

I would recommend using jQuery and some of it's Flash Plug-ins on the client side.  Then in the server I'd just RegisterClientScriptBlock that would set the properties of the flash movie as you need them.

Here's a link to a [jQuery Flash Plugin](http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a javascript library called SWFObject. Then, from your code behind you can register a startup script using the client script manager that loads the movie that you want.

Here is a link to the project: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/